# Blender 2.82 program won't load but previous version of blender works great

Tags: versions

Newest version of Blender 2.82 won't start.

A pop up about AMD drivers quitting appears and Blender shows Not Responding at the top. The screen remains gray.

Using Windows 8 64-bit
Blender 2.79 worked fine.

all windows updates have been installed.
Drivers are all up to date.

Anyone else having this issue? Any ideas?

[image: drivers message]

[image: Not responding]

[image: PC Specs]

Comment: Your system likely doesn't fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated GPU or only the integrated one as shown in your screenshot?

Comment: This was already reported for this on the bug tracker in [T74100](https://developer.blender.org/T74100), therefore this can be closed. The cause for the issue is unsupported hardware (AMD GPU with TeraScale architecture).

Comment: This is a laptop that I have.